# Laravel и PHP 7

Tags: php, laravel, path

Ларавель 5.6 поддерживается только на PHP 7.1.3++ ... поставил новый xampp, версии выше. Мучался с переменной PATH на винде. Каким-то образом получилось добиться того что

```
php -v
PHP 7.2.4 (cli) (built: Mar 28 2018 04:46:46) ( ZTS MSVC15 (Visual C++ 2017) x86 )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
```

Проект создал без ошибок. Захожу в проект на php storm, на php-v выдает 5 версию, проверяю из той же директории команду, только по cmd - нормально 7. Я бы жил спокойно...какая мне то разница. Но оказывается есть разница - При попытке создать модель из консоли шторма

```
php artisan make:model Heroes --migration
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '?' in C:\xampp7\htdocs\projects\heroes\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\helpers.php on line 242

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?' in C:\xampp7\htdocs\projects\heroes\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\helpers.php on line 242
```

А вот из cmd все работает

Потом после того как я покопался в переменных, из консоли шторм вообще не понимает о чем речь, когда я начинаю с php...Что за напасть?

Comment: Привет. В одном обзоре нашел информацию по последней версии Laravel 6.5, он теперь теперь не поддерживает HHVM, только PHP 7.1.3+ и выше. Посмотри https://kinsta.com/blog/php-7-hhvm-benchmarks/

Answer (score 0):

[image: Settings -> ...]

Что у вас тут в настройках (Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> PHP)? Возможно используется старый интерпретатор.